# plsql creating an upsert/merge logic into table before insert from type object

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I have a procedure being used in Post base rest API in Oracle,  I am capturing data from json payload to parse into plsql TYPE and inserting into table without any validations or process on input data.
I want to insert the record on basis of ID column if ID already exist it should update the whole record.
Here is my Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCESS_SF_INV_ORACLE_T (p_data  IN  BLOB)
AS
  TYPE t_hdr_tab IS TABLE OF XX_SF_ORACLE_INVOICE_T%ROWTYPE;
 

  l_hdr_tab     t_hdr_tab := t_hdr_tab();
 

  l_clob         CLOB;
  l_dest_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_lang_context PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
  l_warning      PLS_INTEGER;

  l_hdr_count   PLS_INTEGER;
  l_response    VARCHAR2(4000);
  
BEGIN

  -- Convert the BLOB to a CLOB.
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(
    lob_loc => l_clob,
    cache   => FALSE,
    dur     => DBMS_LOB.call);

  DBMS_LOB.converttoclob(
   dest_lob      => l_clob,
   src_blob      => p_data,
   amount        => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
   dest_offset   => l_dest_offset,
   src_offset    => l_src_offset, 
   blob_csid     => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
   lang_context  => l_lang_context,
   warning       => l_warning);
   
  APEX_JSON.parse(l_clob);

  
  l_hdr_count := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'data');
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_hdr_count LOOP
    
    l_hdr_tab.extend;
    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).ID := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2(p_path => 'data[%d].rows.ID', p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).NAME   := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path  => 'data[%d].rows.NAME',   p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).NET_INV__C     := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path  => 'data[%d].rows.NET_INV__C',     p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).PRICE__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.PRICE__C',       p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).QUANTITY__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.QUANTITY__C',       p0 => i);    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).LOCATION__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.LOCATION__C',       p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).CREATEDDATE       := APEX_JSON.GET_DATE (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.CREATEDDATE',       p0 => i);
    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).STATUS       := 'U';    
        
    
  END LOOP;
  
  
  -- Populate the tables.
  FOR i IN l_hdr_tab.first .. l_hdr_tab.last LOOP
  
    INSERT INTO XX_SF_ORACLE_INVOICE_T VALUES l_hdr_tab(i);
   
  END LOOP;   
 
  
  COMMIT;

  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(lob_loc => l_clob);
  
  
  l_response := 'Success';  
  
  htp.prn('{"status":"'||l_response||'"}');
  
  
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_response := 'Not Success'; 
    htp.prn('{"status":"'||l_response||'"}'); 
  
  --  HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Above code is currently Inserting data into table but don't understand how to update on behalf of ID column

Comment: do you have a primary key index over the table on the field ID ??

Comment: yes ID is primary key column

Comment: ok, I will post an option although I could not test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a PRIMARY KEY constraint over ID, you can use DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception and update the table based on the iteration. I was not able to test it but I could compile the procedure without issues.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCESS_SF_INV_ORACLE_T (p_data  IN  BLOB)
AS
  TYPE t_hdr_tab IS TABLE OF XX_SF_ORACLE_INVOICE_T%ROWTYPE;
 

  l_hdr_tab     t_hdr_tab := t_hdr_tab();
 

  l_clob         CLOB;
  l_dest_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_lang_context PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
  l_warning      PLS_INTEGER;

  l_hdr_count   PLS_INTEGER;
  l_response    VARCHAR2(4000);
  
BEGIN

  -- Convert the BLOB to a CLOB.
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(
    lob_loc => l_clob,
    cache   => FALSE,
    dur     => DBMS_LOB.call);

  DBMS_LOB.converttoclob(
   dest_lob      => l_clob,
   src_blob      => p_data,
   amount        => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
   dest_offset   => l_dest_offset,
   src_offset    => l_src_offset, 
   blob_csid     => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
   lang_context  => l_lang_context,
   warning       => l_warning);
   
  APEX_JSON.parse(l_clob);

  
  l_hdr_count := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'data');
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_hdr_count LOOP
    
    l_hdr_tab.extend;
    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).ID := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2(p_path => 'data[%d].rows.ID', p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).NAME   := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path  => 'data[%d].rows.NAME',   p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).NET_INV__C     := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path  => 'data[%d].rows.NET_INV__C',     p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).PRICE__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.PRICE__C',       p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).QUANTITY__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_NUMBER (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.QUANTITY__C',       p0 => i);    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).LOCATION__C       := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.LOCATION__C',       p0 => i);
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).CREATEDDATE       := APEX_JSON.GET_DATE (p_path    => 'data[%d].rows.CREATEDDATE',       p0 => i);
    
    l_hdr_tab(l_hdr_tab.last).STATUS       := 'U';    
        
    
  END LOOP;
  
  
  -- Populate the tables.
  FOR i IN l_hdr_tab.first .. l_hdr_tab.last LOOP
    -- begin block 
    begin
        INSERT INTO XX_SF_ORACLE_INVOICE_T VALUES l_hdr_tab(i);
        exception when dup_val_on_index 
        then 
            update XX_SF_ORACLE_INVOICE_T U 
            set u.NAME        = l_hdr_tab(i).name ,
                u.NET_INV__C  = l_hdr_tab(i).NET_INV__C ,
                u.PRICE__C    = l_hdr_tab(i).PRICE__C , 
                u.QUANTITY__C = l_hdr_tab(i).QUANTITY__C ,
                u.LOCATION__C = l_hdr_tab(i).LOCATION__C ,
                u.CREATEDDATE = l_hdr_tab(i).CREATEDDATE,
                u.STATUS      = l_hdr_tab(i).STATUS
           where U.ID = l_hdr_tab(i).ID ;
    end;               
  END LOOP;   
 
  
  COMMIT;

  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(lob_loc => l_clob);
  
  
  l_response := 'Success';  
  
  htp.prn('{"status":"'||l_response||'"}');
  
  
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_response := 'Not Success'; 
    htp.prn('{"status":"'||l_response||'"}'); 
  
  --  HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```